# A free-flowing grid system (must be IE 8 compatible)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

At the moment, I have a tabular-style grid system, using a combination of `inline-block` and `width`. I do need to clarify that the `<div>`s I'm using in the jsFiddle contain text, while in reality, they'll each contain a table with a varying number of rows.

The sections are of unequal heights with the `height` value being calculated by the content. I'm not using Bootstrap, and I don't intend to.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u33puLdL/1/) is a jsFiddle of what I currently have, along with a diagram [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7gK1.png).

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QltxY.png) is what I'm trying to achieve with this code. I should note that I've already tried changing it to `display:block` in combination with `float:left` and I couldn't achieve my goal.

The idea is that I'm trying to eliminate the unnecessary whitespace where a section on one side may be three times taller than the opposite side.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how I could approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, by wrapping your `sections` with an `article`(could be `div`), and give that article the `display:table-cell` instead of `#content`, plus some minor changes

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #555;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
h2 {
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 0;
}
#content {
  background: navy;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 70%;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 44% padding: 0 2%;
}
section {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 5%
}
```

```html
<main id="content">
  <article class="cell">
    <section>
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel enim sed urna maximus viverra at et turpis. Nulla ut tortor ac erat consequat consectetur.Ut consectetur id massa convallis gravida. Nulla eget urna pharetra, pretium enim et, facilisis
        est. Praesent sit amet erat nec ligula rhoncus semper non sed purus.</div>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article class="cell">
    <section>
      <h2>Section 4</h2>
      <div>Morbi ac fringilla mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis eu ex erat.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 5</h2>
      <div>Vestibulum eleifend est purus, sit amet cursus lorem rutrum vel. Etiam vel volutpat tellus. Maecenas vehicula convallis lobortis. Praesent quis lorem quis purus bibendum condimentum eu id arcu. In laoreet ut est nec fermentum.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 6</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </section>
  </article>
</main>
```

### UPDATE

based on OP comments, here is a responsive solution to meet OP requirements:

```css
* {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
    background: #efefef;
    color: #555;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
h2 {
    padding: 1.5em 0 0 0;
}
#content {
    background: navy;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 2em;
    width: 70%;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;   
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:0 2%;
}

section {
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin:5%;
  padding:5%
}

@media (max-width:1920px) { /* this will go from 1920px to 1280px */
   .cell {
    width: 44%;

   } 
}
@media (max-width:1280px) { /* this will go from 1280px to 480px */
   .cell {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;    
   } 
}
@media (max-width:480px) { /* this will go from 480px to 0px */
   .cell {
     width:100%;
    display:block
   } 
}
```

```html
<main id="content">
  <article class="cell">
    <section>
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel enim sed urna maximus viverra at et turpis. Nulla ut tortor ac erat consequat consectetur.Ut consectetur id massa convallis gravida. Nulla eget urna pharetra, pretium enim et, facilisis
        est. Praesent sit amet erat nec ligula rhoncus semper non sed purus.</div>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article class="cell">
    <section>
      <h2>Section 4</h2>
      <div>Morbi ac fringilla mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis eu ex erat.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 5</h2>
      <div>Vestibulum eleifend est purus, sit amet cursus lorem rutrum vel. Etiam vel volutpat tellus. Maecenas vehicula convallis lobortis. Praesent quis lorem quis purus bibendum condimentum eu id arcu. In laoreet ut est nec fermentum.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 6</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </section>
  </article> 
    <article class="cell">
    <section>
      <h2>Section 7</h2>
      <div>Morbi ac fringilla mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis eu ex erat.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 8</h2>
      <div>Vestibulum eleifend est purus, sit amet cursus lorem rutrum vel. Etiam vel volutpat tellus. Maecenas vehicula convallis lobortis. Praesent quis lorem quis purus bibendum condimentum eu id arcu. In laoreet ut est nec fermentum.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section 9</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </section>
  </article> 
</main>
```

Comment: @dippas Would it be possible to achieve this without confining a specific number of `<section>` elements to a row, as I'd like the entire website to be completely fluid. What I have at the moment works from 240p up to 4K perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what are you talking about, did you check  this in full page? this is "responsive" so it will adapt any monitor you have, regarding # of `section`s you can add how many you want

Comment: @dippas Within each `<article>` element, you have three sections, but I see what you mean now. I was just looking at the code in the wrong manor. Many thanks for this. :)

Comment: @dippas Oh, hold on, I remember now. While I can add as many `<article>`s as I want, with as many `<section>`s as I want, is there a method to make this flexible horizontally? As in, at 240 pixels, one `<article>` in width, two at 1280 pixels, three at 1920 pixels, etc, using media queries. Someone did mention a jQuery method to accomplish what I'm after but for some reason deleted it. I wouldn't mind using JS, since IE8 already needs it for the semantic elements anyway. Those using IE8 with JS disabled are going to be such a small demographic, I'm not concerned about it.

Comment: Ya there is, its call [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), I'll update my answer to meet your concerns.

Comment: Please see update answer and test it in various widths

Comment: @dippas Perfect! Sorry for the confusion and I knew about media queries, I was just wondering if they could somehow be implemented with this. That's exactly what I was after. Many thanks. :)